Regression discontinuity with panel data using rdrobust
I'm doing regression discontinuity using rdrobust in R
I have question about data format that I have to use in rd.
My data look like this



Date
id




2024-01-01
1


2024-01-01
2


2024-02-01
1


2024-02-01
2




It is repeated cross-sectional data. And I stacked it as if it is one cross-sectional dataset to use in rdrobust.
What I want to know is
If I put this data in
rdrobust(y=y,x=margin,fuzzy=data$fuzzy,kernel='tri')

Does rdrobust consider this data as panel? If it is considered as cross-sectional data, I think there can be a cross-sectional correlation so that standard error will not be properly calculated.
If I put time fixed effect
factor = factor(month(data$Date))
time = model.matrix(~factor)
rdrobust(y=y,x=margin,fuzzy=data$fuzzy,kernel='tri', covs = time)

Does doing this solve the problem and I can interpret the result is came from panel data?
